# How do I use refs in react native enzyme tests when mounting with jsdom?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, enzyme, jsdom

When mounting a component (using jsdom) with a child component that has a ref="nav", I expect this.refs.nav to be the child Navigator in componentDidMount.  I get blank this.refs object when I console.log(this.refs) in componentDidMount.

The component below renders and works fine in the ios simulator, however refs are blank using enzyme's mount.  I have also noticed that if I have a ref on the root element, that particular ref *is* defined in componentDidMount.

I am using:

```
"react": "^15.4.1",
"react-native": "^0.39.2",
"chai": "^3.5.0",
"enzyme": "^2.7.0",
"jsdom": "^9.9.1",
"mocha": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-mock": "^0.2.9"
```

**setup.js**
runs before all tests

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
global.__DEV__ = true;
global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};
require("react-native-mock/mock");
```

**TEST**

```
describe("MyComponent", function() {
  it("does a thing", function() {
    const view = mount(<MyComponent/>);
    expect(...);
  });
});
```

**COMPONENT**

```
const routes = [
  {id: "location", index: 0},
  {id: "rate", index: 1},
  {id: "genres", index: 2},
  {id: "availabilities", index: 3}
];

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.refs); // {}
  }

  renderScene() {
    return return <Button ref="test" title="Hello" onPress={() => { } } />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Navigator
          ref="nav"
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          initialRouteStack={routes}
          sceneStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
          configureScene={() => Object.assign(Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump, { gestures: {} })}
        />
        <TouchableHighlight ref="prev" key="prev" onPress={this.handlePressPrev}>
          <Text>Prev</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight ref ="next" key="next" onPress={this.handlePressNext}>
          <Text>Next</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

this.refs is blank because ref belongs to the navigator component which is not rendered which is not rendered.

You might have noticed the ShallowRenderer doesn't have docs for a ref() method, while the MounedRenderer does. If you want to test refs you have to mount.

In case of navigator component you need to give `ref` parameter to every component in `renderscene()` function.

Comment: I am using mount.  Please delete this answer, it doesn't look like you read the question.

Comment: I have updated my question with the definitions of renderScene and routes.  I had not tried adding a ref to the child in render scene, however it does not help.

Comment: console this.refs.nav.

Comment: console.log(this.refs.nav); // undefined

Comment: Use callback style for ref like this: ref= {(data) => { this.nav = data; }}

Comment: Also tried that, still does not work.  Pretty sure this is a bug or unsupported feature in enzyme.  I dont think it's a case of "doing it wrong".

Comment: what i think using the ref inside the functional components don't have instances.

Comment: instead of using this.refs use view.refs and here viewis our const who is assigned in TEST